# JSON Post wont return error - or run through success

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm calling an ajax post to get data. According to firefox the request is going through and the web service is running a 200 ok message. When I test on the webserver it's fine...but when I try and run this i just get a blank alert every time:

```
$('#btnReg').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://blanked.com/Register.asmx/RegisterUser",
            data: { UserName: "Tom", Password: "Fucker" },
        success: function(data)
        {
            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
               alert( "Val:" + val);
            });

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
    });
```

No error is ever returned

The json returned is:

{"SessionID":"4244d6ecf3e2c69361da09d63e09dd16308be2c679d39f434fa85d48ea0ee2ed"}

Comment: I put this code in a fiddle and I'm getting a "302 Found," not a "200 OK."  Don't know if that's a problem--I would expect the browser to automatically follow the redirect.

Comment: Is blanked.com the actual site you're hitting, or was that changed for this post?

Comment: It's been changed for the post, It private i'm afraid

Comment: What content type does the JSON you are getting have? What happens if you look at `data` before passing it to `each`?

Comment: You are getting a blank alert. That means the the error function is firing. Look at the `thrownError` argument! (Also look at the JavaScript error console).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there's a problem with the data you're receiving from the server. If the server is responding with JSON then:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; **any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown**. **As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected**; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.) [emphasis added]

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

EDIT:

The error function takes a few other argument:

```
error
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
```

Can you alert the values of textStatus and errorThrown arguments.